# 4 Variable System of Equation

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

At the end of a problem I'm solving, I have a series of equations including 4 variables. It is as follows:

x = y/4 + z/7 + m/7

y = 6x/13 + 2z/7 + 3m/7

z = 3x/13 + y/4 + 3m/7

m = 4x/13 + y/2 + 4z/7

x + y + z + m =1

I should find the value of x. What method should I follow? I've been trying so hard on it for a while and I'm clueless now :(

Comment: "I've been trying so hard": what did you try, precisely ?

Comment: Tried to do Gaussian and variable elimination.

Comment: And what went wrong ?

Comment: I just could not find the right answer, then I doubted using Gaussian. Now I see that I'm just bad at artihmetics.

Comment: I confirm that the coefficients do not simplify nicely.

Comment: Yes exactly! Thank you for trying it.

Comment: Use least common multiple and then put the system in a matrix form.

Comment: what do you mean @CroCo

Comment: @Ceren: What CroCo meant is likely to "clear out denominators", eg., your first equation is the same as $28x-7y-4z-4m=0$. Write the system with the first 4 equations in matrix form and [row-reduce the coefficient matrix](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=RowReduce%5B%7B%2828%2C-7%2C-4%2C-4%29%2C%28-42%2C91%2C-26%2C-39%29%2C%28-84%2C-91%2C364%2C-156%29%2C%28-56%2C-91%2C-104%2C182%29%7D%5D). It is not full-rank and the general solution is $(x,y,z,m)=\left(\frac{13}{28}k,~\frac 67k,~\frac 34k,~k\right)$ for any scalar $k$. Use the last equation to get a unique solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want the answer, wolframalpha.com can help (https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x+%3D+y%2F4+%2B+z%2F7+%2B+m%2F7%2C+y+%3D+6x%2F13+%2B+2z%2F7+%2B+3m%2F7%2C+z+%3D+3x%2F13+%2B+y%2F4+%2B+3m%2F7%2C+m+%3D+4x%2F13+%2B+y%2F2+%2B+4z%2F7%2C+x+%2B+y+%2B+z+%2B+m+%3D1), which would give you x=13/86.

But in general, such a system of linear equations is solved through gaussian elimination (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination#Example_of_the_algorithm)

Comment: Thanks. I tried Gaussian, must have calculated stuff wrong since numbers are complex.

Comment: @Ceren numbers are not complex.

Comment: I know, I meant complicated